# Change configuration once, and gets multiple config change history

Tags: jenkins

I work with a Jenkins server in which JobConfigHistory plugin is installed.
This server has been used for a while, and I think many other plugins are installed as well.

On this server, I get multiple config change history recorded when I make a change to job configuration.
I don't want this behavior; I want only single history change for a single configuration change.

I guess some Jenkins server config or some installed plugin is the cause of this problem, but I have no clue what I should do to find it out.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Jenkins issue that has been resolved recently:

[[JENKINS-22224] one job configuration change results in three Job Config History entries](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22224).

But:

> [Danny Staple added a comment - 20/Nov/14 5:17 PM](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22224?focusedCommentId=216575&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-216575)
>
> [We are seeing a general problem here - some of the plugins appear (parameterizedTrigger, ThrottleConcurrentbuilds, NodeLabel, ExtendedChoice are current suspects) to do this too - we are now having as many as 8 (!!) saves in the config. For some plugins, it seems that when there is no change, they save a no-diff config. Almost as if each is doing their own save in order.](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22224?focusedCommentId=216575&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-216575)
>
> ---
>
> [Marc Günther added a comment - 20/Nov/14 5:23 PM](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22224?focusedCommentId=216576&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-216576)
>
> [+1](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22224?focusedCommentId=216576&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-216576)
>
> [We are not using disk-usage plugin anymore, cause it's so slow, but I still see this behaviour. So it's definitely not restricted to disk-usage plugin alone....](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22224?focusedCommentId=216576&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-216576)

Comment: I noticed the issue is just the case.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin persists the changes whenever the configurable entity is saved regardless there is any change or not. Note there is a global option for the plugin *Do not save duplicate history* to save only unique changes.